# What's the equivalent to "SELECT * FROM x WHERE y <= 5 in DAX from POWERBI

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I need to use "WHERE" filter in my DAX consult.

```
Total de Financeiro para Dt_vencimento = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('posicao_renda_fixa'[Financeiro]),
    ALLSELECTED('posicao_renda_fixa'[Dt_vencimento])
)
```

This is the formula

I need something like (but in DAX syntax)

```
SELECT SUM(Financeiro) FROM posicao_renda_fixa WHERE Dt_vencimento <= 720
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
Total de Financeiro para Dt_vencimento = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('posicao_renda_fixa'[Financeiro]),
    'posicao_renda_fixa'[Dt_vencimento] <= 720
)
```

Comment: What's wrong with my answer? Didn't it solve your problem?